# I'm a dancer. What am I?

Tags: riddle, haiku

> I dance, wiggling;
> A wiggle there, and one here.
> She sees and follows.
>
> Then she leaves for good.
> My face creases to a smile.
> I run off to nurse.

What am I?

Comment: Creases into a smile, like smiling.

Comment: I thought smile was 2 syllables. :P

Comment: Apparently wiggling is 2 syllables.

Comment: Q: I'm a dancer. What am I? A: A dancer, duh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this could be...

> A bee.

```
I dance, wiggling;
A wiggle there, and one here.
She sees and follows.
```

> Bees do a dance (called the [waggle dance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waggle_dance)) to indicate to other bees the direction of a food source they found. The worker bees are all female, so another bee (she) sees the dance and follows the instructions/direction encoded in the dance to go off and find the food.

```
Then she leaves for good.
My face creases to a smile.
I run off to nurse.
```

> The waggle dance can also be used to indicate the direction and distance to a potential new nesting site. "she leaves for good" refers to the queen leaving when the colony swarms to a new location. If a bee thinks they have found a really good site or food source, their dance will be more energetic, so they are actually competing with other bees in the sense that they are trying to recruit their kin to go to *their* resource site. When they are successful, they are happy as the colony will be healthy. Running off to feed the larvae (nursing) is one of the many duties of a worker bee.

Comment: You did it! YAY!!!